# 'System.Collections.Dictionary' does not contain a definition for 'Selected'

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple web form in C# with Dropdown list and Checkbox list and a button which displays the selected item on click event.

Here is my Code Snippet :

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "In the DropdownList you selected: " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "<br /> ";


    foreach (ListItem Item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (Items.Selected == true)
        {
            Label1.Text += " In the CheckboxList you selected: " + Items.Values + "<br />";
        }

    }
```

and here is the error which I get whenever I run it on the browser :

**Error 1** 'System.Collections.IDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Kindly help me in solving this error. can't figure out where am I doing it wrong..!!

thanks.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your code

```
 if (Item.Selected == true) // you put Items here
```

or you can try this

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = (from item in chkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
                               where item.Selected 
                               select int.Parse(item.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it works fine and there was some minor glitch in CheckboxList as well, resolved that on my own. :)